# Ordering matrix columns in Python based on variable names and subscripts

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, matrix

Using python, order the columns of this matrix according to the variables indicated in the first row where the column titles are. So first all the X's go, then the Y's and finally the B's.

The order is first all the Xi , being i a numerical index, then there are the Yi, being i a numerical index, and lastly is column B

```py
matriz = [['Y1', 'X2', 'X3', 'Y3', 'Y2', 'X5', 'X4', 'X1', 'B'],
          [   1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1,   5],
          [   1,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,   6],
          [   1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,   5],
          [   1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,   5],
          [   0,    0,    1,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,   3],
          [   0,    0,    1,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,   0],
          [   0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    1,    0,    0,   1]]
```

Code 1:

```py
#IT HAS THE PROBLEM THAT IT DOES NOT ORDER WITH THE SUBINDICES OF THE VARIABLES, 
# BUT IS ONLY LIMITED TO ORDERING BY THE NAMES OF THE VARIABLES
matriz_ordenada = matriz

#the code sorts the matrix matriz_ordenada based on whether the first element of each row (previously a column) 
# starts with the letter "Y" (and then do the same with "B"). 
#The sorting is performed by transposing the matrix, sorting the rows/columns, 
# and then transposing it back to its original form.

matriz_ordenada = sorted(zip(*matriz_ordenada), key=lambda x:x[0].startswith("Y"))
matriz_ordenada = list(map(list, zip(*matriz_ordenada)))

matriz_ordenada = sorted(zip(*matriz_ordenada), key=lambda x:x[0].startswith("B"))
matriz_ordenada = list(map(list, zip(*matriz_ordenada)))
```

Code 2:

```py
# Extract the variable names and subscripts from the first row
variables = matriz[0]

# Sort the variables based on the variable names and subscripts
variables = sorted(variables, key=lambda x: (x[0], int(x[1:])))

# Create a mapping of variable names to column indices
column_indices = {var: i for i, var in enumerate(variables)}

# Reorder the columns of the matrix
matriz_ordenada = [list(row) for row in zip(*matriz)]
matriz_ordenada = [matriz_ordenada[column_indices[var]] for var in variables]
matriz_ordenada = [list(row) for row in zip(*matriz_ordenada)]
```

Then simply, using one code or the other, I print the matrix that should be obtained already sorted using the column titles as criteria

```py
print(matriz_ordenada)
for row in matriz_ordenada: print(row)
```

**Wrong output** with **code 1**:

```
['X2', 'X3', 'X5', 'X4', 'X1', 'Y1', 'Y3', 'Y2', 'B']
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 5]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 6]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

**Wrong output** with **code 2**:

```
    variables = sorted(variables, key=lambda x: (x[0], int(x[1:])))
  File "C:\backup\programacion lineal con python\resolver_sel.py", line 59, in <lambda>
    variables = sorted(variables, key=lambda x: (x[0], int(x[1:])))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

And this is the **correct output** with the matrix with its columns ordered according to their column titles or column names (which are strings) :

```py
matriz_ordenada = [
    ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3', 'B'],
    [   1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,   5],
    [   0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,   6],
    [   0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    1,    0,    0,   5],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    1,    0,    0,   5],
    [   0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,   3],
    [   0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1,   0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    1,   1]
]
```

Comment: Please edit your tags to use the proper `python` tag rather than the `python-3.x` tag, which is reserved for questions that specifically apply to python 3, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# remove the "B" column
b = [row.pop() for row in matrix]

# get the column names sorted
column_order = [i for _, i in sorted(zip(matrix[0], range(len(matrix[0]))))]

# iterate through the rows and columns
matrix = [[row[i] for i in column_order] for row in matrix]

# put the "B" column back in the last position
[row.append(b[i]) for i, row in enumerate(matrix)]
matrix
"""
    [['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3', 'B'], 
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5], 
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 6], 
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 5], 
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3], 
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]]
"""
```

Comment: Why you write a line only with `matrix` after this code line `[row.append(b[i]) for i, row in enumerate(matrix)]` ?

Comment: just to print the matrix ‍♂️